# php file upload problems post_max_size already fixed

Tags: php, file-upload

So i have been working on this for two days now and i am still at a loss, i might the lack of sleep. I went ahead and changed my php.ini to accept post_max_size to 100M, restarted my server and so some reason i am still not getting anything from the var dump. what am I doing wrong. should i not be expecting any files at this point? I just want to see if my file has been uploaded.

```
<?php

var_dump($_FILES);

?>


<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <input id="image-file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your file input has no "name" attribute

```
<input id="image-file" type="file" />
```

vs

```
<input id="image-file" type="file" name="attachment" />
```

Comment: Hmm... still doesn't work properly should i be looking for $__FILES or $__POST?

Comment: `$_FILES`, I've tested your code with my change and it works as expected.